# How to simplify a Matcher

Tags: unit-testing, dart

I have implemented my own Matcher for testing that every element of in a `List<List<T>>` has a length of 0.  The test seems a bit verbose and I was wondering if there is a way to simplify it.

```dart
void main() {   
  Board board = new Board(10,10); // board.pieces is a List<List<Piece>>
  test('All pieces have a length of 0', () => expect(board.pieces,everyElement(length) ));
}

class LengthMatcher extends Matcher {
  final int _length;
  LengthMatcher(this._length);
  bool matches(item, Map matchState) => item is List && item.length==_length;

  Description describe(Description description) =>  description.add('A List with a length of $_length');
}
LengthMatcher length = new LengthMatcher(0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument for everyElement is named `matcher` but is has no type and therefore is `dynamic`.
Supported are matchers and functions.

```dart
import 'package:unittest/unittest.dart';
import 'package:matcher/matcher.dart';

void main(args) {
  List<List<int>> board = [[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]];

  test('', () {
    expect(board, everyElement((List e) => e is List && e.length == 0));
  });
}
```